# Is there a way to access power profile of an android device?

Tags: android

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/xml/power_profile.xml - this link gives a sample of the power profile which are actually dummy values for each interface and its power consumption in various states.

Since this is device dependent and the responsibility of OEM to fill it before shipping the device, is there a way to access it via android framework APIs or even from the native layer ?

Answer (score 0):

Official [documentation](https://source.android.com/docs/core/power/values) leads to the file destination

> /frameworks/base/core/res/res/xml/power_profile.xml

On Samsung devices this file is placed

> /system/framework/framework-res.apk/res/xml/power_profile.xml

file placed inside the APK, but you can disassemble them via [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/).

I was also interested in the content of the file. I tried to get some info from several devices, and actually got pretty useless info. So I doubt if the content is valid.

*upd:*

But appeared there is a mechanism to override those values. And so the proper power_profile.xml is contained in the vendor's

> /system/vendor/overlay/framework-res_auto_generated_vendor.apk/res/xml/power_profile.xml

Hard to evaluate if that file is valid properly, but it`s content looks properly. It would be nice if somebody will provide some more light on the topic.